# iOS need reusable table view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

*ios 7.1*

**Summary**: When user segues to new table view controller, system allocates too much memory that's why I need some kind of re-usable or singleton table view controller.

---

I have a table view controller (let say vertical home) which has inner table view's(horizontal) inside of it's cells. If I wouldn't need to create horizontal tables, I could create a single table and manipulate it's `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method instead creating an inner one.

Anyway there is another functionality; there are buttons inside of the most inner cells and if user taps that, it triggers a push segue which navigates to another table view controller that has same vertical & horizontal structure. It is highly potential that user is going to go to those table view controllers lot's of times.

When monitoring the memory usage of application:

1. If user stays at home view controller and scrolls vertically, system allocates approximately 1 more mb per each cell which has inner table view. 1 mb is acceptable even it is great actually. Btw. I am using reusable cells to be able to decrease memory usage through those lines of code:

   ```
   [tableView registerNib: customCellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:HorizontalContainerTableCellIdentifier];
   cell = (HorizontalContainerTableCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:HorizontalContainerTableCellIdentifier];
   ```
2. If user triggers a segue; a new table view controller is created [as desribed as here.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15869155/1659451) and even if user doesn't scroll system allocates around 5 mb per each table view controller.

That means cost of creating a new view controller for each segue is too much. I can accept that my view hierarchy is not light weighted but as it can be seen in the 1st usage scenario if user scrolls vertically system is re-using pre-created cells and memory cost is not that much.

So which way should I follow? Do I need to subclass segues and redirect them to pre-initialized view controller and update it's table ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15869741/1659451))? By this way I can force the system to reuse cells. Or is everything normal and is it how it's supposed to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that was my mistake. Because the controller view which contains the most outer table view was not releasing at all. When I profile via instruments I have seen couple instances of same controller despite I have popped them already.

The root cause of that, ARC was expecting GUI elements defined as `weak`. I have changed property definitions as `weak` instead `strong`. Then ARC started to release controller instances.

However I have still memory problem. Because I am creating image context for each cell which consumes memory a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you segue viewController, the older viewController will be pushed into the navigation stack and a new viewController will be created and also pushed into the stack. I think you can make the usage less by freeing tableView data in `viewWillDisappear` and reload them on `viewWillAppear`. Just trigger `reloadData` and return `0` in `numberOfRowsInSection`that will free the memory used by tableView.

Comment: Well, it sounds hacky but will do the trick I think. Only clue in my mind is; flushing a table view at each time `viewWillDisappear` called maybe expensive job to achieve for device. As I said if it's easy to achieve for device, that's great.

Comment: The user won't see the flash here if you load your data locally, but if you get them from the "internet", then it would be a better idea to show progress dialog here. That's what I do by the way in my app, to control memory usage.

Comment: I called `reloadData` from `viewWillDisappear` and returned 0 but that didn't removed memory allocation. I think I need to remove view controller from storyboard or sth. like this.